# Search a 2D Array for a string of another 1D Array and then put them in a new 2D with the sorting of the 1D

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting, search

This title must be really confusing, so let me explain my problem.

I have a one-dimensional Array (let's call it "ids") which is sorted in the way I need it to be.

Then, I have another 2D Array which contains a name on position 0 and an id in position 1 (let's call  it "names").

So names[0][0] = name, names[0][1] = id.

Let me clarify that the 2 arrays are not of the same length!

What I want to do it so create a new 2D Array which has a name and an ID, but sorted like my one dimensional array (the ids are in the same order like they are there).

What I've tried so far is this (and all I am getting is a text file full of nulls):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
            String equal = ids[i];

            for (int j = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                if(users[j][1].equals(equal)) {
                    sortedArray[i][0] = users[j][0];
                    sortedArray[i][1] = equal;
                }
            }

        }

        for (int i=0; i<sortedArray.length; i++){
            writer.println(sortedArray[i][0]+"\t"+sortedArray[i][1]);
        }
```

It might not be of any use, but since I am creating these by reading files, this is the rest of my code:

```
BufferedReader reader;
        BufferedReader reader2;
        PrintWriter writer;

        String[][] users = new String[39431][2];
        String[] ids = new String[22890];
        String[][] sortedArray = new String[22890][2];

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("allConnectedUsers.txt"));
        reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ids.txt"));

        String sorted = "sortedNamesWithIDs.txt";
        writer = new PrintWriter(sorted, "UTF-8");

        String usersline = reader.readLine();
        String idsline = reader2.readLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            String splittedLine[] = usersline.split(" ");
            String name = splittedLine[0];
            String id = splittedLine[1];
            users[i][0] = name;
            users[i][1] = id;
            usersline = reader.readLine();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            String onlyIDs;
            onlyIDs = idsline;
            ids[i] = onlyIDs;
            idsline = reader2.readLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed it. It was a pretty dumb mistake.

In the nested loop, I wasn't checking for "j" or increasing it, but i.

Sorry for this dumb mistake, thanks if you even read it.